# Cython: dynamic "cdef extern from xxx"

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I am trying to get direct access to `numpy` functions `random/randomkit.h` to use random generators in a multithreaded application with cython (i.e. without the gil).

To that end I am trying to access the header file from numpy's folder using the following code:

```
import os
import numpy

str_rkdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(numpy.__file__))
str_randomkit_h = str_rkdir + "/random/randomkit.h"

cdef extern from str_randomkit_h:
   ctypedef struct rk_state
   cdef unsigned long rk_random(rk_state * state) nogil
   cdef signed long rk_gauss(rk_state * state) nogil
   cdef void rk_seed(unsigned long seed, rk_state * state) nogil
```

However, this does not work with `pyximport` because cython complains about the `str_randomkit_h` string (I guess it doesn't interpret the python code before compiling)... is there a simple way around this?

As a dirty workaround, I'm dynamically generating the `.pxd` before the cython compilation but this does not really feel nice so I was wondering whether there was a better way to do it.

Comment: This type of thing is usually handled by the build script. Can you have "setup.py" add the correct directories to the build path?

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean! The fact is (and I should probably have specified this) I'm using pyximport for convenience and I think this requires the absolute path but I'll check again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically you can't get it work that way because, as you also stated, there is no interpreting going on, only compiling. `DEF`s won't help either because the functions that can be used in the preprocessing stage are limited. I don't believe there is some other sneaky way to do this; you need to use `pyximport` or a `setup.py` script.

With `pyximport` you can supply appropriate arguments to the `install` function. The directory/ies containing the include file(s) can be given as a value in the `setup_args` dictionary with the key `'include_dirs'`:

```
>>> from numpy import random as rnd    
>>> from pyximport import install
>>> install(setup_args={'include_dirs':rnd.__path__[0] + '/'})
```

Of course, doing this implies you also change your `.pxd` file to supply the header name as a string literal:

```
cdef extern from "randomkit.h": 
    ...
```

Alternatively, [using a setup script](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/building.html#building-c-and-c-extensions-with-distutils) is pretty straightforward. Again, you just supply the `include_dirs` after computing them in some fashion.

Comment: ok, this is good, thanks a lot for the explanation and the link!